# Stubbing controller methods in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, minitest, stub, ruby-mocha

I have some code like this:

```
new_method = lambda do
  puts "Hey, I'm the new method!"
  redirect_to login_path
end

MyController.any_instance.stubs(:my_method).returns(new_method)
```

The problem is it's returning the lambda, instead of calling it...

So how do I stub controller methods? Or to put it differently, how do I stub a method and return a block to be run?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had no luck with `mocha`, but `minitest/mock` does run lambda blocks, but only for class methods:

```
require 'minitest/mock'

new_thing = lambda do
  puts "hi"
end

MyController.stub :my_class_method, new_thing do
  MyController.my_class_method
end
```

To get instance methods stubbed, you can either get `@controller` if you are in a controller test and stub that, or get another gem https://github.com/codeodor/minitest-stub_any_instance, which lets you do this:

```
new_thing = lambda do
  puts "hi"
  redirect_to login_path
end

MyController.stub_any_instance :my_method, new_thing do
  visit my_controller_method_path
end
```